# how to know which columns are updated in a table in Oracle 11g with out using triggers and auditing

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, audit-trail

Table name is employees

```
ID NAME SALARY  

1 K1 2000  
2 K2 3000  
3 K3 4000
```

Now,i updated the 2nd row( 3000 with 9000)

```
ID NAME SALARY

1 K1 2000  
2 K2 9000  
3 K3 4000
```

Now,i want oracle command to know which columns are updated,with out using triggers.
For Example: if i give table name " employees " then the command should say " SALARY " column is updated.
If i give column name " SALARY " then it must say the Column " SALARY " is  changed. If i give column name as " NAME " then it must say column " Name " is not changed.Thank you friends.

Comment: Didn't you ask this a few days ago? I can't see it now, but as I recall you hadn't answered any of the clarifying questions asked in comments on that question. Such as, whether you wanted a permanent record, if you just needed to know in the current session, if flashback is available for the period you're interested in; and more generally why you need this and why you can't use triggers.

Comment: i should not use triggers and auditing in my project. where in my project i will send sql command to oracle databases and execute it. the result is captured from front end.

Comment: Still not clear what you want I'm afraid. Are you talking about one command, so you do an update and want know which values actually changed at that point (e.g. `update employees set salary = 2000 where id = 1` wouldn't actually change anything) - which you could potentially do with a wrapper procedure - or are the update and check for changes independent, and some time apart? Why are you restricted in the mechanism you can use, and ruling out built-in functionality?

Comment: If I correctly understand your requirement, then there is no such command in Oracle which will tell you last DML activity on a column. As I said, if you enable auditing, it will be simple for you. Or else, I will have additional columns in the table like `timestamp` and log these details in history table which will need a trigger.

Comment: thank you, iam trying with auditing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **Fine grained auditing**. `DBMS_FGA` is an in-built package provided by Oracle to add **policies**. See [**documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_fga.htm) for more insight.

For example,

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE empno = 9998;
INSERT INTO emp (empno, ename, sal) VALUES (9998, 'Bill', 1);
UPDATE emp SET sal = 10 WHERE empno = 9998;
DELETE emp WHERE empno = 9998;
ROLLBACK;

-- Check the audit trail.

CONN sys/password AS SYSDBA
SELECT sql_text FROM dba_fga_audit_trail;

SQL_TEXT
--------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE empno = 9998
INSERT INTO emp (empno, ename, sal) VALUES (9998, 'Bill', 1)
UPDATE emp SET sal = 10 WHERE empno = 9998
DELETE emp WHERE empno = 9998

4 rows selected.
```

This is just an example, where all DML actions were audited. There are other audit options:

- DDL (CREATE, ALTER & DROP of objects)
- DML (INSERT UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT, EXECUTE).
- SYSTEM EVENTS (LOGON, LOGOFF etc.)

Have a look at [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/auditing-10gr2) article by Tim Hall.

Comment: thank you for your response. sorry for not mentioning in question heading. i must not use triggers and auditing. i must execute only command to get the result. I don't know this is possible or not.

Comment: @kiran Auditing is a feature. Once enabled, all you need to do is use simple SQ to get the result.

Comment: @kiran If it is not enabled, obviously it won't audit. See the article I posted.

Comment: @kiran I updated my answer, and added link to documentation. Please mark it as answered, would help others.

Answer (score -1):

With `dbms_flashback` (oracle 9i) or the `AS OF TIMESTAMP` clause in your select query for latter versions of Oracle. See https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/flashback-10g#flashback_query for further information on usage.

> Flashback Query allows the contents of a table to be queried with
>   reference to a specific point in time, using the `AS OF` clause.
>   Essentially it is the same as the `DBMS_FLASHBACK` functionality or
>   Oracle 9i, but in a more convenient form. For example.
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE flashback_query_test (
>   id  NUMBER(10)
> );
>
> SELECT current_scn, TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM v$database;
>
> CURRENT_SCN TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAM
> ----------- -------------------
>      722452 2004-03-29 13:34:12
>
> INSERT INTO flashback_query_test (id) VALUES (1);
> COMMIT;
>
> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM flashback_query_test;
>
>   COUNT(*)
> ----------
>          1
>
> SELECT COUNT(*)
> FROM   flashback_query_test AS OF TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP('2004-03-29 13:34:12', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
>
>   COUNT(*)
> ----------
>          0
>
> SELECT COUNT(*)
> FROM   flashback_query_test AS OF SCN 722452;
>
>   COUNT(*)
> ----------
>          0
> ```